# Comparing variables

Tags: android

I'm writing a game and I am storing the players top score as a SharedPrefrence. I am using this method so that when the user exits the application, his top score stays. I have everything coded up until that point. I now want to implement a way to display the new top score when the player plays the game again. The logic behind this is that If the first top score is greater than zero, display the first top score. Then when the game is played again, if the second top score is greater than the first top score, display the second top score, else display the first top score. In my head, I would think a simple If/else statement would suffice, but my problem comes into play when declaring the first variables. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. It just displays the new score--even if it is a lower value than the first score which is what I don't want. Any help would be much appreciated. Code:

```
TextView textSavedWeek2ms2_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ts02);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
String strSavedWeek2ms2_1 = sharedPreferences.getString("top_score", "");
String topscore = strSavedWeek2ms2_1;
int topscore1 = Integer.valueOf( topscore);  

if (topscore1 > 0 )                 
    { 
        textSavedWeek2ms2_1.setText(topscore);
    }
    else 
        textSavedWeek2ms2_1.setText("0");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably unintended:

```
if (topscore2 > topscore2){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a typo....

```
if (topscore2 > topscore2)                 
{ 
    textSavedWeek2ms2_1.setText(topscore);
}
```

**So it should be**

```
if (topscore2 > topscore1)                 
    { 
        textSavedWeek2ms2_1.setText(topscore);
    }
```

Comment: Correct. What I had made no sense. Haha. That's what I get for being up all night. I have updated the code to display the initial score. But What I cannot figure out is how to display the new result ONLY if it is greater than the first. Any thoughts? I tried several ways but they all seem to require me to declare the variable which resets it's value oncreate.